# How to run command in a different folder using EcsOperator Airflow

Tags: airflow, amazon-ecs

The command I want to run in the container is this:

```
/bin/bash -c "cd /opt/project/A && ls"
```

Basically I'm using this python code to override the command in the container:

```
        return ECSOperator(
            task_id=task_id,
            cluster=runOncluster,
            task_definition=task_definition,
            overrides={
                'containerOverrides': [
                    {
                        'name': task_definition,
                        'command': ['/bin/bash', '-c', '"cd', '/opt/project/A', '&&', 'ls"']
                    }
                ]
            },
            region_name=region,
            launch_type="EC2",
            group=task_definition
        )
```

However I have an error saying:

```
/bin/bash: -": invalid option
```

Also I tried this other command, simpler, but I nothing is executed:

```
['cd', '/opt/project/A', '&&', 'ls']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one that works is this:

```
["/bin/bash", "-c", "cd /opt/project/A && ls"]
```